# Groovy: How to execute complex shell command in groovy?

Tags: shell, groovy

I would like to be able to execute a nested shell command.  For example;

```
final String cmd = 'for i in pom.xml projects.xml; do find . -name $i | while read fname; do echo $fname; done;done'
```

I had tried the following syntax but wasn't able to get it running.

1. `def result = cmd.execute();`
2. `def result = ['sh', '-c', cmd].execute();`
3. `def result = ('sh -c for i in pom.xml projects.xml; do find . -name $i | while read fname; do echo $fname; done;done').execute()`

I would appreciate the help here.

Comment: why not either write a shell script and execute that,  or just write some groovy that performs the same function?

Comment: It would be so much easier if I can execute that in Groovy.  I could have done this within Groovy but the above is just an example as I can have more complex commands; something it will take longer to implement in Groovy.  If there is no easy way to call shell commands within Groovy then I will have to create a separate shell script but now I have to track another script file.

Comment: presumably, this failed silently?

Answer (score 7):

This should work:

```
def cmd = [
  'bash',
  '-c',
  '''for i in pom.xml projects.xml
    |do
    |  find . -name $i | while read fname
    |  do
    |    echo $fname
    |  done
    |done'''.stripMargin() ]

println cmd.execute().text
```

(I've formatted the command text so it looks better here, you could keep it all in one line)

I also believe your command could be replaced by:

```
find . -name pom.xml -o -name projects.xml -print
```

Or, in Groovy:

```
def files = []
new File( '.' ).traverse() { 
  if( it.name in [ 'pom.xml', 'projects.xml' ] ) {
    files << it
  }
}

println files
```

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for all the help.  This is a great community.  I was able to get this working after passing in the environment and working directory information.

```
def wdir = new File( "./", module ).getAbsoluteFile() ;
def env = System.getenv();
def envlist = [];
env.each() { k,v -> envlist.push( "$k=$v" ) }
final String cmd = 'for i in pom.xml projects.xml; do find . -name $i | while read fname; do echo $fname; done;done'
proc = ["bash", "-c", cmd].execute(envlist , wdir);
```